# Get NICs interfacetype

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

When using Windows Firewall, one can specify an `interfacetype` for its rules, using the possible values `lan`, `wireless` or `ras`.

The problem is that Windows sometimes gets this classification wrong: An existing NIC is classified into the wrong interfacetype. Is there any way to determine which of the types a NIC is classified into? Maybe even adjust it if Windows gets it wrong?

Comment: Try `wmic nic get adaptertype, name` and see if that helps any from command line. Not sure if it's wrong when Windows sometimes gets it wrong for your scenario but maybe that'll help you.

Comment: That brings up completely other types as `lan`, `wireless` and `ras`: There are a few `Ethernet 802.3`, `Tunnel` or empty fields in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough...

If it's wired using an ethernet cable, it's LAN ([Local Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)).

If it has no wiring, it's wireless ([Wifi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi)).

A domestic setup is unlikely to be employing any kind of RAS ([Windows Remote Access Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_access_service)) structure.

Comment: That's how it *should* be, but apparently, Windows sometimes gets this classification wrong. Is there any way one can see and check it?

Comment: If you're sitting at the computer, look round the back. Your question doesn't really fully describe the scenario, so I took the simplest path. Visual.

Comment: Of course I can look at the cables, but I want to know what Windows actually thinks about the types, not what it *should* think.

Comment: Then your question needs to be a whole lot clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to improve it, do you think it is better now?